# Azure Atlas api Get Search POI doesn't bring back similar results as does a single word search query does for Bing comparatively

Tags: geolocation, bing-maps, bing, azure-maps, bing-search

Here is my get query

```
'https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/poi/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key=keygoesherexxxxxxxx&query=HOSPITAL&limit=7&lat=28.46538&lon=-81.47917&radius=100000'
```

The query is `HOSPITAL` which is the same with the Bing.com search. 
Here are the results

```
 medical_locations: [
    MedicalLocation {
      name: 'Doctor Anika Alar MD',
      city: 'Orlando',
      street_number: '6900',
      street_name: 'Turkey Lake Rd',
      postal_code: '32819',
      url: 'https://rheumatologyorlando.com',
      phone: '+(1)-(407)-2093711',
      freeform_address: '6900 Turkey Lake Rd, Orlando, FL 32819',
      distance: 0.35
    },
    MedicalLocation {
      name: 'Orlando Health Winnie Palmer Center for Maternal Fetal Medicine-Spring Lake',
      city: 'Doctor Phillips',
      street_number: '7243',
      street_name: 'Della Dr',
      postal_code: '32819',
      url: undefined,
      phone: undefined,
      freeform_address: '7243 Della Dr, Doctor Phillips, FL 32819',
      distance: 0.76
    },
    MedicalLocation {
      name: 'Orlando Health Physicians Urology Group',
      city: 'Doctor Phillips',
      street_number: '7243',
      street_name: 'Della Dr',
      postal_code: '32819',
      url: undefined,
      phone: undefined,
      freeform_address: '7243 Della Dr, Doctor Phillips, FL 32819',
      distance: 0.76
    },
    MedicalLocation {
      name: 'Doctor Green Relief Orlando Marijuana Doctors',
      city: 'Orlando',
      street_number: '6000',
      street_name: 'Turkey Lake Rd',
      postal_code: '32819',
      url: 'https://www.drgreenrelief.com/locations/orlando-marijuana-doctors/',
      phone: '+(1)-(407)-8016500',
      freeform_address: '6000 Turkey Lake Rd, Orlando, FL 32819',
      distance: 0.81
    },
    MedicalLocation {
      name: 'Universal Studios Health Services',
      city: 'Orlando',
      street_number: undefined,
      street_name: 'Canal St',
      postal_code: '32819',
      url: undefined,
      phone: undefined,
      freeform_address: 'Canal St, Orlando, FL 32819',
      distance: 1.02
    },
    MedicalLocation {
      name: 'Clear Sinus-Orlando',
      city: 'Doctor Phillips',
      street_number: '7601',
      street_name: 'Della Dr',
      postal_code: '32819',
      url: undefined,
      phone: '+(1)-(407)-9561522',
      freeform_address: '7601 Della Dr, Doctor Phillips, FL 32819',
      distance: 1.11
    },
    MedicalLocation {
      name: 'MD & NP 2 Me',
      city: 'Doctor Phillips',
      street_number: '7380',
      street_name: 'W Sand Lake Rd',
      postal_code: '32819',
      url: 'mdnp2me.com/',
      phone: '+(1)-(844)-6367263',
      freeform_address: '7380 W Sand Lake Rd, Doctor Phillips, FL 32819',
      distance: 1.12
    }
  ]
```

The results from the bing search are:

```
Orlando Health - Dr. P Phillips Hospital
 Yelp (85) · Hospital
9400 Turkey Lake Rd, Orlando · (407) 351-8500
Open 24 hours
DIRECTIONS
WEBSITE
Sand Lake Surgery Center
 Yelp (5) · Health & Medical
7477 Sandlake Commons Blvd, Orlando · (407) 264-9633
Closed · Opens tomorrow 6 AM
DIRECTIONS
WEBSITE
Arnold Palmer Hospital for Children
 Yelp (35) · Hospital
92 W Miller St, Orlando · (407) 649-9111
Open 24 hours
DIRECTIONS
WEBSITE
Orlando Health - Winnie Palmer Hospital for Women & Babies
 Yelp (74) · Hospital
83 W Miller St, Orlando · (321) 843-2584
Open 24 hours
DIRECTIONS
WEBSITE
Orlando Health Orlando Regional Medical Center
 Yelp (61) · Hospital
52 W Underwood St, Orlando · (321) 841-5111
Open 24 hours
DI
```

As you see the Bing.com results are way better and accurate compared to the atlas Azure map search. I can't really see anything from the payload response to filter the data any better either.

There is everything polluted in the results from rheumatology to marijuana doctors.

How can I properly search for hospitals and or urgent care clinics in the results and that's all?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Maps has a large number of POI categories that can be used to refine the results to the specific categories you are interested in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/supported-search-categories

There are several health care and hospital related categories to choose from. I believe that HOSPITAL_POLYCLINIC is the category that is more inline with what you are looking for.

Your query only returns the first 7 results. The furthest result is 1.12 miles. However looking the the Bing.com results you mentioned, the first result is more than 2.5 miles away.

Comment: thanks. I think Hospital_poly is what I am getting returned. I will try to see if that alters the result any. It would be nice to further divide that category as in that search . I checked there is no difference. What I could do though is only return names in the title that have hospital in them. Perhaps hospital, urgent care, and womens... something like that. I will post the code as I fix it.

Comment: There are a bunch of sub categories documented:

HEALTH_CARE_SERVICE: blood bank, personal service, personal care facility, ambulance unit, health care service, leprosarium, sanatorium, hospital, medical center, clinic

HOSPITAL_POLYCLINIC: special, hospital of Chinese medicine, hospital for women children, general, hospital/polyclinic

some results will have multiple categories specified in the `classifications` property.